# Editor for an Interpreter in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

How to put line numbers in a text editor widget in GUI present in Cincom Visual Works 7.7. This will used by the user to enter the sample instruction set line line by giving each line a number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a property that supports this or not.  If there isn't you can always extend the text editor to include this feature.